# Questions related to Service Fabric and .Net Framework > 4.5.2

Tags: azure, azure-devops, devops, azure-service-fabric

We are currently using service fabric application (runtime version: 5.1.163.9590). I understand that there are newer versions out there. But my questions are generic.

The visual studio template for creating new service fabric application (for the above runtime) defaults to .NET Fraemwork Version 4.5.2. But we would like to use .NET Framework 4.6.x. (I know that some versions of C# compiler is backward compatible but I don't want to rely on any of this except for a given .net framework version). I also know that there are ways to package .net framework upgrade to desired version. But there was a concern that if you scale up the cluster, the desired .net framework will not be part of new nodes.

We would like to target a particular .net framework (say 4.6.2 or 4.7 etc.) and upgrade our code to compile to this version of .net framework.

My questions are:

1. How should we deploy the initial cluster so that a given .net framework version (say 4.6.2) deployed on all nodes?
2. When we scale up cluster with additional nodes, what steps should we take so that the all nodes are deployed with a chosen version in previous step?
3. Assuming the cluster has been running for a while, how can we smoothly upgrade to next .net framework version (say 4.7) without any problems during upgrade or scaling up (assuming we compile our code to .net framework 4.7 and re-deploy)?

We are looking for repeatable process (to avoid production issues) that need to be followed by both development and operational team members. In other words, we are looking for best practices in this area.

Any additional information is welcome.

Comment: What's the reason to use > 4.5.1 just out of interest?

Comment: Take advantage of new features that come with each version and not worry about whether the compiler is backward compatible or not etc.

Comment: Understood. I don't know how to do it with scale sets, but my personal preference is to stay on supported .NET framework. In any case changing this will add on to deployment/upgrade time significantly.

Comment: "why >4.5.1" because it's 2017; 4.5.1 is 2013; because 4.5.1 hasn't been supported for over a year! because security & perf updates; 4.6 has useful things like Task.Completed; RyuJIT; better GC...
Need I go on?

Comment: Any one from microsoft?

Answer (score 0):

Q: How should we deploy the initial cluster so that a given .net framework version (say 4.6.2) deployed on all nodes?

A: Please have a look at PowerShell Desired State Configuration(DSC). You can have a DSC script that ensure a particular version of .Net is install 
http://code.commongroove.com/2016/08/09/powershell-dsc-script-resource-dot-net-4-6-2/

Q:When we scale up cluster with additional nodes, what steps should we take so that the all nodes are deployed with a chosen version in previous step?

A:Similar to the previous one, maintain a DSC script for your node configuration when you add a new node run DSC to make sure your machine is configured as other node.

Q: Assuming the cluster has been running for a while, how can we smoothly upgrade to next .net framework version (say 4.7) without any problems during upgrade or scaling up (assuming we compile our code to .net framework 4.7 and re-deploy)?

A: This will depend on your application however I will use a two phase approach. Basically, you split your cluster in two. One active and handling trafiic. Upgrade non-actives, direct the traffic then upgrade the other.

Hope that helps